# How do I deal with the uploaded file data manually?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to save the uploaded file manually for learning, without the help of `request.files`.

I am using Flask and it's giving me a `str` type of the raw body data, by `print(type(reqeust.data))`

1. I get confused. Shouldn't I get binary data `<type bytes>` instead?

---

But then I think again, even if I get binary data, how can I filter the first several lines and then start to read the binary data from the right place?

For exmaple:

```
-----------------------------1699415032232102060211780227
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="Screenshot from 2018-10-05 15-49-07.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG

�ߧd�tEXtSoftwaregnome-screenshot��>�IDATx���OPY����l�*c���=��El"f[��)3��S�+z-v�0�c������zp����6��qS�\W��6S�qM�S=tG�Ǩb��A�ؒvc���@rh��.N]���?JK����b+�J��(�����OR�T
-----------------------------1699415032232102060211780227--
```

2. Could someone teach me how could I save the file data manually?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "manually"?

Comment: @roganjosh Retrieving the (PNG) file data and save it on the server, by using python file input/output functions.

Comment: So, without using `.save()` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792270/saving-an-uploaded-file-to-disk-doesnt-work-in-flask)? What issue are you trying to get around?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, without using `save()` provided by the framework. I just want to know how I could save the the file manully just like `save()` does.

Comment: The `save` method is [here]((https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L2778)), so you might piece together the process it goes through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out by myself.

1. The reason why I am getting `str` from `request.data` is because I was using `python2.7` flask packages. Such a pain in the ass. I would definitely use `virtualenv` next time, even for testing. But I still don't understand why  I can use python3 syntax in the server code while the package is related to python2.7.
2. So actually I am getting raw byte data like `b'raw binary data'` from `request.data`. And data from other functions e.g. like `request.form['firstname']` have already been decoded.

So now the question boilds down to how I can rebuild the file, provided the binary data.

---

Af first, I prepare 2 small files for testing.

file1: `1.txt`

content: `1234567`

file2: `test.png`  this small image ------> [image]

content (use `open('test.png', 'rb').read()`):

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa4\xafB\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x10tEXtSoftware\x00Shutterc\x82\xd0\t\x00\x00\x00\x15IDAT\x08\xd7c\xd4\xe5Tb\xc0\x01\x98\x18p\x83\xa1"\x07\x00T;\x00h\xb9\x9335\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

So the `request.data` I see on the server is:

```
b'-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="1.txt"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n1234567\r\n-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile2"; filename="test.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa4\xafB\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x10tEXtSoftware\x00Shutterc\x82\xd0\t\x00\x00\x00\x15IDAT\x08\xd7c\xd4\xe5Tb\xc0\x01\x98\x18p\x83\xa1"\x07\x00T;\x00h\xb9\x9335\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82\r\n-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076--\r\n'
```

Format it a little bit:

(The data can't be used directly because I added extra new lines for displaying.)

```
b'-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076\r\n  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="1.txt"\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n
1234567\r\n
  -----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076\r\n 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile2"; filename="test.png"\r\n
Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n
\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa4\xafB\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x10tEXtSoftware\x00Shutterc\x82\xd0\t\x00\x00\x00\x15IDAT\x08\xd7c\xd4\xe5Tb\xc0\x01\x98\x18p\x83\xa1"\x07\x00T;\x00h\xb9\x9335\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82\r\n
-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076--\r\n'
```

---

Let `raw_data = binary data above`

1. `files_data_array = raw_data.split(b'-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076\r\n)`

Then I get an array with each files in different index.

Here `files_data_array[1]` contains the first file meta info and data. `files_data_array[2]` contains the second file meta info and data. And so on if you have more files.

```
[b'', b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="1.txt"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n1234567\r\n', b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile2"; filename="test.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa4\xafB\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x10tEXtSoftware\x00Shutterc\x82\xd0\t\x00\x00\x00\x15IDAT\x08\xd7c\xd4\xe5Tb\xc0\x01\x98\x18p\x83\xa1"\x07\x00T;\x00h\xb9\x9335\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82\r\n-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076--\r\n']
```

2. `file2_data = files_data_array[2]`

```
b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile2"; filename="test.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa4\xafB\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x10tEXtSoftware\x00Shutterc\x82\xd0\t\x00\x00\x00\x15IDAT\x08\xd7c\xd4\xe5Tb\xc0\x01\x98\x18p\x83\xa1"\x07\x00T;\x00h\xb9\x9335\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82\r\n-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076--\r\n'
```

Then split the meta by `file2_meta_info = file2_data.split(b'\r\n\r\n', maxsplit=1)[0]`.
Notice that here I am splitting binary data, and in case there are `b'\r\n\r\n'` in the file data, settting `maxsplit` is necessary.

Now  I get `file2_meta_info` as `b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="1.txt"'`, I can decode it and get whatever meta info I want.

Now turn to the file body data itself, `file2_body_data = file2_data.split(b'\r\n\r\n', maxsplit=1)[1]`

I get

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa4\xafB\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x10tEXtSoftware\x00Shutterc\x82\xd0\t\x00\x00\x00\x15IDAT\x08\xd7c\xd4\xe5Tb\xc0\x01\x98\x18p\x83\xa1"\x07\x00T;\x00h\xb9\x9335\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82\r\n-----------------------------16866548741414816351605255076--\r\n'
```

I still need to cut some bytes, compared to the content of `test.png` showed at the beginning

`real_file2_body_data = file2_body_data.rsplit(b'\r\n', maxsplit=2)[0]'`

Finally I can rebuid the file with :

```
f = open('test2.png', 'wb')
f.write(real_file2_body_data)
f.close()
```

Done!

Comment: Sorry for the messy variable naming :P. And b y reinventing the wheel, now I feel relaxed about what's happening under the hood. And for other languages which don't provide `b'binary data'.split()`, one can always use low level function to search the specific byte and do the same splitting.